# Failed to compile. Module not found: Can't resolve for assets Nextjs

Tags: nextjs, javascript-import, vercel

estoy tendiendo este error cuando hago deploy a Vercel o Netlify de mi proyecto de NextJS, localmente funciona, tanto en desarrollo como producción. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la libreria "yet-another-react-lightbox" con el componente  que tiene una propiedad "slide" que recibe un array de StaticImageData[], no de strings.

A las imágenes las tengo en la carpeta publica y esta es la estructura

```
public/images/projects/folderproject/image.jpg
```

Ya trate diferentes maneras de importar las imágenes pero no funciona, solo en local.

```
"../../../public/images/projects/romano/main.jpeg" 
"/public/images/projects/romano/main.jpeg" 
"/images/projects/romano/main.jpeg" 
"public/images/projects/romano/main.jpeg"
```

Y esta es el script para importar las imágenes y exportarlas en un arreglo de imágenes

```
"src/assets/images/portfolio.ts"

import notas1 from 'public/images/projects/notas/Screenshot_20221221-153023.png'
export const notas = [notas1]
```

El componente es este y funciona bien tanto en produccion como desarrollo en cualquier lado que lo use, todo localmente.

```
<Lightbox open={open} close={() => setOpen(false)} slides={notas} render={{ slide: GalleryPortfolio }}/>
```

De cualquier manera dejo el link al repositorio del proyecto en caso de que no me haya explicado bien https://github.com/Cristian021195/website ¡gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo solucioné de una manera extraña, lo que hice fue agregar un archivo myassets.ts al folder principal del proyecto "/myassets.ts" y a ese archivo puse todas las rutas de las imágenes que necesitaría, (en los arreglos las que usa Ligthbox)

También quiero aclarar que probé de las otras formas con "@/" y tampoco dio resultado, me gustaría saber el porqué, si alguien luego tiene una respuesta deje el comentario. Dejo link a nuevo repo [homepage](https://homepage-mauve-alpha.vercel.app/) es una demo para portfolio